# How to insert a page at the end of a document?

Tags: c#, vsto

I am doing some VSTO development for Word using C#. I am having a hard time figuring out how to insert a page(a .docx file) at the end of my active document.

Answer (score 0):

```
WORD._Application app = new WORD.Application();
WORD._Document doc = app.Documents.Open ... ;
WORD.Selection selection = app.Selection;
object breakType = WORD.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak;
selection.InsertBreak(ref breakType);
```